re-run run with a single stage
I know that it is possible to re-run a certain stage in yaml, but if my pipeline has a single stage, seems that the stage box (where the re-run button is) is not available. How can I re-run a single stage run?

Any reason why you need to re-run a single-stage pipeline? Why not queue a new build?

Hi @RuiJarimba, reason is rollback: re-deploy a previous version for whatever reason as it was done when first time (pipeline may have changed)

You can solve that problem with a proper branching strategy. Or, as a workaround, add a dummy stage to your pipeline :-)

You can also create a temporary branch from the commit that contains the changes to be reverted and queue a new build from that new branch. But the dummy stage might be the simplest workaround for you.

As far as I know, pipeline variables (mostly secrets in our case) are not stored in yaml, so can not be recovered from the old commit. Dummy stage was also my alternative, but seems quite far away from an "elegant" workaround (every user will ask "why the hell is this here doing nothing?")

Re-running a stage or running a new build from same branch can be complicated, so many things can change between builds: secrets, tools, shared YAML templates, etc
Not sure if re-running the same stage will help with the secrets - for example, if you use variable groups or a task to download keyvault secrets and these change between the first run and the rollback you won't be using the same values. Regarding why the hell is this here doing nothing? - just document it properly - comments are your friend :-)

Based on your command:

reason is rollback: re-deploy a previous version for whatever reason as it was done when first time (pipeline may have changed)

You can try to manually trigger the pipeline to run for the previous code version. When you manually trigger the pipeline, you can specify which commit the new run will run for.
The pipeline will use the version of YAML file from the specified commit instead of the current latest YAML file. So, it will run the same jobs and steps as the first run previous.


EDIT:
When a build/run has only a single stage defined, there is no option to rerun the stage on the web UI of this build/run.
As a workaround, you can use the Azure DevOps REST API "Stages - Update" to rerun the single stage in the build/run. It can force rerun the whole of the specified stage.
See below example as reference.

The YAML pipeline.

# azure-pipelines.yml

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    . . .

  - job: A2
    displayName: 'Job A2'
    steps:
    . . .


The PowerShell script to call the REST API.

$organization = "organization-name"
$project = "project-name"
$buildId = 3752
$stageRefName = "A"
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/stages/${stageRefName}?api-version=7.0"

$pat = "Personal Access Token"
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

$body = @{
    forceRetryAllJobs = $true
    state = "retry"
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body


Result.





Thank u for your answer @Bright Ran-MSFT. The result is not comparable to what you get with a stage redeploy, which preserves the input vars and the pipeline vars (at least).

Users do not understand why is so "direct" with multistage pipelines and not so agile with single stage ones. I thought that the same option was hidden somewhere

@Josto, When a build/run has only a single stage defined, there is no option to rerun the stage on the web UI of this build/run. As a workaround, you can use the Azure DevOps REST API "Stages - Update" to rerun the single stage in the build/run. For more details, see EDIT in my above answer.

Hi @Bright Ran-MSFT, seems and interesting workaround. Do you think that something like that can be added as extension to the organization (as a run context menu option or something) to be easily triggered by users? This for sure would replace the missing feature!

@Josto, I agree that it would be great if there is an menu item or button on the web UI for user to rerun the single stage. I tried to search in the Marketplace, but did not find any extensions can provide such menu item or button.

@Josto, Maybe, you can reference the the documentation Develop extensions and Extension samples to try to develop an extension for this feature. You also can try to report a feature request on Developer Community.

Thank u @Bright Ran-MSFT, I'll look into this to see what I can do.
